# What does the index method do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The one that can be inside ApplicationController and other classes that extend it. Is it executed right after the application is started or when the controller is called? What is it for?

Comment: It usually powers index/list pages of corresponding resources and this is described in every single rails book/tutorial.

Comment: I just read a tutorial and it didn't quite explain what it's for and what it does. They just used it. I'm still confused.

Comment: What was that tutorial?

Comment: This tutorial: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app

Comment: Read it again, now pay more attention. You missed [the explanation](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app#sec-mvc_in_action). (the list under the figure)

Comment: `index` is a controller action. [CRUD, Verbs, and Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) explains how the default mapping works. In addition, you can run [`rails routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes) on the command line to see the actual mappings for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The `index` method in a controller is used to return a collection of models. For example, an `index` method inside `PostsController` should return a collection of `Post` models.

You usually don't declare this method inside your ApplicationController but instead make one specific for the resource you're allowing access to

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

Comment: I see. I'm starting to get it.